# Percona XtraDB Cluster 5.6 не запускается

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, cluster, percona

Всем доброго дня. Хочу запусть в тестовых целях Percona XtraDb Cluster на ubuntu 14.04. За основу взял вот этих две статьи

1. https://habrahabr.ru/post/152969/
2. https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/5.6/manual/bootstrap.html

Дошел до места

> Ну и в завершение, перезапускаем демона:

И не запускается он у меня

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start  
 * Starting MySQL (Percona XtraDB Cluster) database server mysqld 
 * The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64.pid).
   ...fail!
```

В логах несколько ошибок. Ошибка номер один:

> [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

Естественно запускал `mysql_upgrade`, но он не отрабатывает

> $ sudo mysql_upgrade
>   Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
>   FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed

Ошибка номер два:

> 160502 14:56:26 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>   160502 14:56:26 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE
>   ENGINE failed. 160502 14:56:26 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage
>   engine: InnoDB 160502 14:56:26 [ERROR] Aborting

Все советуют удалить все из папки `/var/lib/mysql` и якобы начинает работать. Но я удалил и ничего не заработало.

Мой конфиг my.cnf

```
[mysqld_safe]
# wsrep_urls=gcomm://192.168.33.101:3400,gcomm://192.168.33.102:3400,gcomm://
#wsrep_urls=gcomm://192.168.33.101:3400,gcomm://

[mysqld]
innodb_log_file_size=256M
wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://192.168.33.101
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
basedir=/usr
user=mysql
log_error=/var/log/mysql.err
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_sst_receive_address=192.168.33.101:3500
wsrep_node_incoming_address=192.168.33.101
wsrep_slave_threads=2
wsrep_cluster_name=cluster0
wsrep_provider_options="gmcast.listen_addr=tcp://192.168.33.101:3400;"
wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup
wsrep_sst_auth=backup:password
wsrep_node_name=node0
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5000M
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=4M

[client]
port=3306
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**Собственно вопрос:** как запустить? Если есть у кого рабочая конфигурация, то прошу поделиться.